# [chngcntr]: Documentation: \counterwithout Remove All

Tags: counters, chngcntr

In the documentation for package [`chngcntr`](http://mirror.jmu.edu/pub/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chngcntr/chngcntr.pdf),
a command is referenced as:

`\counterwithout{<ctr>}{<..>}`

The phrase:

> Any number of `\counterwithin{<ctr>}{<...>}` and `\counterwithout{<ctr>}{<...>}`
>   commands can be issued for a given counter, `<ctr>`,  if you wish to toggle
>   between the two styles.

Is there a method to list several counters in the `<...>` portion of the code,
or to use a wildcard to remove all reset triggers?

Comment: No, there is no such behaviour of `\counter....` but it can be done with some programming

Answer (score 1):

`chngcntr` does not allow for a list of counter names in the arguments, so each command has to be specified separately or loop through a comma-separated list.

Here are two solutions: One using `expl3` and a direct loop, the other one (at the bottom of this post) uses the `xassoccnt` package (which in turn uses `expl3` as well ;-))

This solution uses an `expl3` `\seq` variable to loop through the counter list in `\CounterWithout` and `\CounterWithin` -- the starred variants are available as well.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\CounterWithout}{smm}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
      \counterwithout*{##1}{#3}
    }
  }{
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
      \counterwithout{##1}{#3}
    }
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CounterWithin}{smm}{%
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#2}
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
      \counterwithin*{##1}{#3}
    }
  }{%
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {%
      \counterwithin{##1}{#3}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CounterWithin{figure,table,equation}{section}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{FooFoo}
\subsubsection{FooFooFoo}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table caption}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\CounterWithout{subsection,figure,table,equation}{section}

\section{Bar}
\subsection{BarBar}
\subsubsection{BarBarBar}


\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table caption}
\end{table}
\clearpage




\end{document}
```

**Another solution with `xassoccnt`**

The `xassoccnt` package provides the commands `\RemoveFromReset` and `\AddToReset` which act on a list of counters and behave otherwise like `\counterwithout*` and `\counterwithin*`, i.e. the commands don't change the counter formatters. (Since I am the author of `xassoccnt`, I have to put this missing counter formatters issue on my to-do-list for the next release)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xassoccnt}



\begin{document}

\AddToReset{figure,table,equation}{section}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{FooFoo}
\subsubsection{FooFooFoo}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table caption}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\RemoveFromReset{subsection,figure,table,equation}{section}

\section{Bar}
\subsection{BarBar}
\subsubsection{BarBarBar}


\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
E=mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{A caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \caption{Another caption of a figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{table}
\caption{A table caption}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in removing the `c`lear `l`ist for a specific counter `<cntr>`, you can reset `\cl@<cntr>`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}% Not needed for this example

\makeatletter
% Empty out the Clear List for a counter
\newcommand{\allcounterwithout}[1]{\@namedef{cl@#1}{}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A section}% 1
\subsection{A subsection}% 1.1

\allcounterwithout{section}% Remove all counter resetting associated with section

\section{A section}% 2
\subsection{A subsection}% 2.2 (should be 2.1 without \allcounterwithout)

\end{document}
```